# Uploading folder to Google Cloud - Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a folder in my local machine to google cloud bucket. I get an error with the credentials. Where should I be providing the credentials and what all information is needed in it.

```
from_dest = '/Users/xyzDocuments/tmp'
gsutil_link = 'gs://bucket-1991'

from google.cloud import storage
try:
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(source_file_name,destination_blob_name))

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

The error is

```
could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/do`cs/application-default-credentials.
```

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: @Dustin edited the question to include this.

Comment: Have you tried following the link in the error message?

Comment: @Dustin That's my main issue. What credentials should I add and how. I just have the link to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You need to acquire the application default credentials for your project and set them as an environmental variable:

1. Go to the [Create service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccountkey) key page in the GCP Console.
2. From the **Service account** drop-down list, select **New service account**.
3. Enter a name into the **Service account** name field.
4. From the **Role** drop-down list, select **Project** > **Owner**.
5. Click **Create**. A JSON file that contains your key downloads to your computer.

Then, set an environmental variable which will provide the application credentials to your application when it runs locally:

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is usually thrown when the application is not being **authenticated** correctly due to several reasons such as missing files, invalid credential paths, incorrect environment variables assignations, among other causes. Keep in mind that when you set an environment variable value in a session, it is reset every time the session is dropped.

Based on this, I recommend you to validate that the credential file and file path are being correctly assigned, as well as follow the [Obtaining and providing service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) guide, in order to explicitly specify your service account file directly into your code; In this way, you will be able to set it permanently and verify if you are passing the service credentials correctly.

**Passing the path to the service account key in code example:**

```
def explicit():
  from google.cloud import storage

  # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
  # file.
  storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')

  # Make an authenticated API request
  buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
  print(buckets)
```